# My ubuntu software center is not loading, how can I repair this defect

Tags: 22.04

How can i deal with an Ubuntu software center that is not loading when I click on it?

Comment: Try running `apt-get update` in Terminal before opening Ubuntu Software Center.

Answer (score 0):

Please, try to run snap-store from terminal

```
snap-store
```

What is the kernel version?

```
uname -r
```